# Angular 4 : Validators.pattern() not working

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, pattern-matching

i am trying to validate input type="text" using pattern , i want only text.

Component :

```
this.from = this.fb.group({
  name: ['',Validators.required,Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z]+$')],
});
```

Html :

```
<input type="text" formControlName="name"/>
```

I have have also tried :

```
this.from = this.fb.group({
    name: ['',Validators.required,Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/)],
});
```

with no effect. Angular 4

Comment: same result....

Comment: I think your `required` is useless since your pattern must match at least 1 character (the plus sign)

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ I need it because without it starts other backend checks. When I type in input I got ERROR Error: Expected validator to return Promise or Observable.

Comment: So you can update the question with the error message. It can be useful to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by adding validators in one array with `[]`:

```
this.from = this.fb.group({
    name: ['',[Validators.required,Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/)]],
});
```

Comment: It's an `array`( `[]`) not an object (`{}`).